# Cannot update variable for quiz

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm making a quiz app right now and my `correct` variable does not seem to ever get updated. I'm calling the `function correctTest()` which correctly gets called if I click the radio function which contains the right answer for the quiz; however, I'm stuck on using the correct syntax to update.

```
$http.put('/quizQuestions', {
  isRight: $scope.quizQuestions[$index][isRight]+1
});
```

I am posting using:

```
  router.put('/quizQuestions', function(req, res) {
    db.quizQuestions.update({
  isRight: req.body.isRight
}, {}, function(err, data) {
  res.json(data);
});
```

});

sorry I had the wrong method copy pasted

Comment: Have you defined `PUT` endpoint for /quizQuestions in node ? I can see only `POST` .

Comment: Can you explain issue bit more ? Its quite unclear.

Comment: You're using `put` in Angular and `post` in Node. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Change `router.post('/quizQuestions', function(req, res) {` to `router.put('/quizQuestions', function(req, res) {`

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

`db.quizQuestions.update({
  <query to find the record to update>
}, {$set:{isRight: req.body.isRight}}, function(err, data) {
  res.json(data);
...`